# ISI PCB NC$9$ Limiting Distribution of Bernoulli to Poisson

Tags: distributions, central-limit-theorem, iid

Let $X_i\sim (i.i.d.)$, Bernoulli($\frac{\lambda}{n}$), $n\ge \lambda\ge 0$.
$Y_i\sim (i.i.d.)$, Poisson($\frac{\lambda}{n}$). $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ are independent.

 Define $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i$ and $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}Y_i$.
 Find the limiting distribution of $\frac{T_n}{S_n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

**My solution:**
Let $p=\frac{\lambda}{n}$
$T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i=\binom{n^2}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n^2-k}$ for some $n\ge k\ge 0$.
Similarly, $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i=\binom{n^2}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n^2-k}$ for some $n\ge k\ge 0$

Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_n}{S_n}=1.$

Is there any mistake in the solution? Please help me to correct it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I don't think what you've written for $S_n$ is correct because it has a binomial pmf instead of a Poisson pmf. In the statement of the problem, $S_n$ is a sum of $Y_i$, but you've written $S_n = \sum_i^{n^2} X_i$

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4199781/321264.

Comment: Work with the characteristic functions instead.